# Show that in a set with at least 3 elements there exist two permutations that do not commute.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the only solution is to swap elements. However, I can not find notations to define. This is what I am trying to show;

Assume X has four elements for the sake of argument X:= {a,b,c,d} then I would let function f swap 1st element with 2nd and 2nd with 3rd, leaving the last element, and I would define function g as swapping last two elements. How would I define them using notations?

Comment: Start with a set of $3$ elements, say $X= \{ 1,2,3\}$. Then the two permutations $(1 \ 2)$ and $(1 \ 3)$ do not commute.

Answer (score 2):

If you swap 1st and 2nd, then you cannot swap 2nd and 3rd anymore at the same time ( with the same permutation). Maybe you want 1 to 2 and 2 to 3, or similar. Try a cycle of length 3, like $f = (a,b,c)$. Also, $g = (c,d)$. Then you can calculate

$$g \circ f \circ g^{-1} = (a,b,d) \ne f$$